# Spring environments difference

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, junit

I keep on studing Spring, and find Spring environment comparison as a very obscure topic. It's very difficult (IMHO) to find something intelligible on the topic.

I've got a vague understanding of the intention of each of Spring environment (mentioned below), but can't grasp the difference between them. I mean, I understand that EJB environment is destined for integration with EJB framework. But has it got some extra-bonuses compared to Standalone? What bonuses? So my questions are:

- *Can you provide me a brief comparison of "extra-bonuses" (means additional functional abbilities except of integration with the framework) of each environment?*
- *Can you explain me what is JUnit environment and for it's destined?*

Environment types:

1. Standalone
2. Web
3. JUnit
4. EJB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only difference between these is how you wish to deploy/run your application.

1. Standalone

   - Run your Java application via a "main" method.
2. Web

   - Deploy your application to a Java web container such as Tomcat, as a .war file.
3. JUnit

   - Run a JUnit test.
4. EJB

   - Access EJBs from your application, which will have been deployed through one of 1-3.

The difference between these environments has nothing to do with Spring. Spring is just a framework, which makes some aspects of an application easier to write.

For instance, in a web environment, Spring provides annotations which make it easy to expose methods in your classes as MVC controller methods, REST or SOAP endpoints. These are obviously things which are commonly needed in web applications.

In a JUnit test, the Spring-Test libraries enable you to wire up a Spring context into your test so that you can test how those components have been wired together. Whether you intend to deploy as a standalone or web application, you should be testing your components with JUnit, or another test framework as part of your build process.

With respect to EJBs, if you also have EJB components (not Spring) deployed, then Spring provides helpers which let you reduce the amount of code involved in locating/invoking them.

Comment: Agreed. I think Steve deserves the Bounty :)

Comment: I also agreed ). Thanks for Steve